# Use GNSS of Win 10 Tablet to show live position in Google Earth Pro

Tags: google-earth

I want to use the GNSS signal of my Windows 10 tablet (Panasonic Toughbook FZ-G2) to show my live position in Google Earth Pro while working in the field. The map data of the area is available offline via caching.

I activated positioning in the Win 10 status bar, and activated realtime tracking in Google Earth via tools, GPS, realtime, protocol NMEA, follow Path automatically and started realtime tracking. After that a realtime-GPS-receiver is added to my locations list but no position is shown on the map. Any Ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a Panasonic to try but I tried this with my desktop PC since I've never tried this feature - this worked fine with an external Bluetooth GNSS connected.  But Google Earth seems to get confused easily and selects an unsuitable Com port, for example I turned the Bluetooth GNSS off then on, Google Earth got stuck on a port which didn't have NMEA.

Are you sure the Panasonic provides NMEA on a Com port?  This would be listed in Device Manager under Ports (COM & LPT).

Comment: I checked the Device Manager and there is indeed no NMEA listed unter COM & LPT.

Comment: Maybe try to set up a virtual COM port on the machine, pipe the NMEA stream through that, and then try to get Earth to connect to it that way?

Comment: A GPS / GNSS port may not have a sensible name depending on how it is connected.  It might be called "Communications Port" if it uses an old-style serial port.  On devices I have to hand, a u-Blox receiver using u-Blox drivers shows up as "u-blox Virtual COM Port", and the GNSS receiver on a Sierra cellular modem is "Sierra Wireless Snapdragon X7 LTE-A NMEA Port". I found a PC Magazine review of G2 which says "4G LTE mobile broadband with GPS" so that model uses the GNSS which is part of cellular modem.